# Issues with DropDownList in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, drop-down-menu, viewdata

```
`//View <tr><td>Experience level</td><td><div class="editor-field">
                    <%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ExperienceLevelID, (SelectList)ViewData["Experience"], "--select--")%>
                    <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ExperienceLevelID) %>
                </div></td></tr>`<tr><td>Size of Company</td><td><div class="editor-field">

                <%: Html.DropDownList("Value", (SelectList)ViewData["size"], "--select--")%>

 public ActionResult Create()//Controller
    {
        ViewBag.mode = "create";IExperienceLevelRepository expLevelResp = new ExperienceLevelRepository();
        IQueryable<ExperienceLevel> expLevel = expLevelResp.GetAllExperienceLevels().OrderBy(ExperienceLevel => ExperienceLevel.Name);
        ViewData["Experience"] = new SelectList(expLevel, "ID", "Name");


        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> companySizes = new List<SelectListItem>
                                             {

                                                 new SelectListItem
                                                     {
                                                       Text = "Large Company",
                                                          Value = "large"

                                                     }
                                             };
        ViewData["size"] = new SelectList(companySizes, "Value", "Text");



        return View();
    }
```

The above dropdownlist works fine for the ViewData["Experience"] But it doesnt works with size , I have to manually hardcode the dropdownlist for size and the experience dropdownlist is populated from db. The error which i m getting for size dropdownlist is :There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'Value'.

Any help or suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would very strongly recommend you to use view models and strongly typed views instead of `ViewData` and weakly typed helpers as they lack Intellisense and are source of many errors and ugly views.

Model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string SelectedExperienceId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Experiences { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string SelectedSizeId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Sizes { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new MyViewModel
    {
        Experiences = new[]
        {
            new SelectListItem { Value = "exp1", Text = "Experience 1" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "exp2", Text = "Experience 2" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "exp3", Text = "Experience 3" },
        },
        Sizes = new[]
        {
            new SelectListItem { Value = "s1", Text = "Size 1" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "s2", Text = "Size 2" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "s3", Text = "Size 3" },
        }
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

Strongly typed view:

```
<%@ Page 
    Language="C#" 
    MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master"     
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<AppName.Models.MyViewModel>" 
%>

...    

<%= Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.SelectedExperienceId,
    new SelectList(Model.Experiences, "Value, "Text"),
    "-- Experience --"
) %>
<%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.SelectedExperienceId) %>

...

<%= Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.SelectedSizeId,
    new SelectList(Model.Sizes, "Value, "Text"),
    "-- Size --"
) %>
<%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.SelectedSizeId) %>
```

Now all that's left is replace the hardcoded values with ones coming from your database, by mapping the returned resultset from the repository into `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`.

Comment: What If i want to run a loop , for instance I want to show values in a dropdown from 0 to 200.

Comment: @Muhammad Awais, in the controller action simply assign `Sizes = Enumerable.Range(1, 200).Select(x => new SelectListItem { Value = x.ToString(), Text = "Size " + x })`.

Comment: thnx .. nd regarding httppost can i get the selected value just by if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {trackdayResp.Add(trackday);
                trackdayResp.Save();}

Comment: @Muhammad Awais, in the POST action you simply reuse the view model as action argument. The `SelectedExperienceId` and `SelectedSizeId` properties will be automatically populated with the user selection. You could check `if (ModelState.IsValid)` before updating the processing them to ensure that the user selected some value from the dropdown lists.

Comment: Will it also add the values to the tables associated with the parent table , for instance events(table) have a relatiosnship with products(table) , derefore on creating an event will also insert values into products (table) related to that event ..

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356269/how-to-get-the-selected-value-from-dropdownlist-in-controller-mvc-2

Answer (score 1):

This gives you two different ways to add items to a list of SelectListItems.  You can bind with an existing collection or you can populate it manually.

```
public List<SelectListItem> GetSomeSelectList()
{
  var items = SomeCollection
              .OrderByDescending(s => s.SomeProperty)
              .Select(s => new SelectListItem { 
                 Value = s.SomeProperty, 
                 Text = s.SomeOtherProperty })
              .ToList();
  items.Insert(0, new SelectListItem { Value = "0", Text = "Some Default" });
  return items;
}
```

I agree with Darin that you should be using view models instead of viewdata.  In my case, I put the above method into a view model and in my view I call that method.

```
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SomeProperty, Model.GetSomeSelectList()) %>
```

Comment: What If i want to run a loop , for instance I want to show values in a dropdown from 0 to 200