# How to get the selected value from dropdownlist in Controller (MVC 2)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, drop-down-menu

I am struggling to get the selected value from the hard-coded dropdownlist in mvc , below is the code:

View:

```
<tr><td>No of Helmets</td><td><div class="editor-field">

                <%: Html.DropDownList("helmets", (SelectList)ViewData["size"], "--select--")%>
                </div></td></tr>

                 <tr><td>No of Garages</td><td><div class="editor-field">
                 <%: Html.DropDownList("garages", (SelectList)ViewData["garages"], "--select--")%>
```

Controller:

// dropdown for helmets

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Event trackday, FormCollection formValues)
    {Product product = new Product();//
        ViewBag.mode = "create";

        // for dropdown track
        ITrackRepository trackResp = new TrackRepository();
        IQueryable<Object> tracks = trackResp.GetVenuesSelectlist();
        ViewData["Venue"] = new SelectList(tracks, "VenueID", "Name");
       var helmets = Enumerable.Range(1, 200).Select(x => new SelectListItem { Value = x.ToString(), Text = x.ToString() });
        ViewData["helmets"] = new SelectList(helmets.ToList(), "Value", "Text");

        // dropdown for garages
        var garages = Enumerable.Range(1, 50).Select(x => new SelectListItem { Value = x.ToString(), Text = x.ToString() });
        ViewData["garages"] = new SelectList(garages.ToList(), "Value", "Text");  product.QtyAvailable = Convert.ToInt32(formValues["garages"]);


        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            trackday.DateAdded = DateTime.Now;
            trackday.DateModified = DateTime.Now;
          //  productResp.Save();//
         //  trackday.Products.Add(product);
            trackdayResp.Add(trackday);
            trackday.Products.Add(product);
            trackdayResp.Save();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            return View();
        }


    }`
```

How can I get the Selected value of the above 2 dropdownlist in mvc post controller.

Comment: Can you show us what you have so far for your post action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've called your dropdowns "helmets" and "garages" if you debug your action and look at the `formValues` dictionary your should see these two values.

Alternatively you could change your model to have a "Helmets" and "Garages" property of type int? and the model binder should populate these values.

Or you could change your action to something like:

```
public ActionResult Create(Event trackday, int? helmets, int? garages, FormCollection formValues)
```

This should be populated with the id's (selected value) of the drop down list.

### Update

Here's my code that gets the values either from the collection or from the passed properties:

HTML:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
  <h2><%: ViewData["helmetsCollectionValue"]%></h2>
  <h2><%: ViewData["helmetsProperty"]%></h2>
  <h2><%: ViewData["garagesCollectionValue"]%></h2>
  <h2><%: ViewData["garagesProperty"]%></h2>
  <% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
  <p>
    <%: Html.DropDownList("helmets", (SelectList)ViewData["size"], "--select--")%>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%: Html.DropDownList("garages", (SelectList)ViewData["garages"], "--select--")%>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </p>
  <% } %>
</asp:Content>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var helmets = Enumerable.Range(1, 200).Select(x => new SelectListItem { Value = x.ToString(), Text = x.ToString() });
    ViewData["helmets"] = new SelectList(helmets.ToList(), "Value", "Text");

    // dropdown for garages
    var garages = Enumerable.Range(1, 50).Select(x => new SelectListItem { Value = x.ToString(), Text = x.ToString() });
    ViewData["garages"] = new SelectList(garages.ToList(), "Value", "Text");

    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(FormCollection collection, int? helmets, int? garages)
{
    ViewData["helmetsCollectionValue"] = collection["helmets"];
    ViewData["helmetsProperty"] = helmets;
    ViewData["garagesCollectionValue"] = collection["garages"];
    ViewData["garagesProperty"] = garages;

    var helmetsList = Enumerable.Range(1, 200).Select(x => new SelectListItem { Value = x.ToString(), Text = x.ToString() });
    ViewData["helmets"] = new SelectList(helmetsList.ToList(), "Value", "Text");

    // dropdown for garages
    var garagesList = Enumerable.Range(1, 50).Select(x => new SelectListItem { Value = x.ToString(), Text = x.ToString() });
    ViewData["garages"] = new SelectList(garagesList.ToList(), "Value", "Text");

    return View();
}
```

Comment: I cant change it to int coz its a collection

Comment: its hsowing nuthing : null  :(

Comment: does the form collection contain helmets and garages? Can you update you question with your complete view?

Comment: I've updated my answer with code showing how it works for me.

Comment: it works fine thnx a lot for ur assistance , one more thing to know is , the helemt is link to product type 1 , whereas the garages is link to product type 2 in my db, so what I was looking for if the client select helmet it should add producttype 1 to the db , vice versa..

Comment: HOW CAN I SHOW DROPDOWNLIST'S SELECTED VALUES ON NEXT PAGE ON WEBGRID?